Как импортировать произвольный файл?
Есть имя файла вида "file.py", и надо импортировать файл с таким именем. Как это сделать?

Для динамического импорта файлов можно сделать следующее:

Использовать функцию __import__() (не рекомендуется)

__import__(name, globals=None, locals=None, fromlist=(), level=0)


Использовать модуль importlib

import importlib

importlib.import_module(name, package=None)


Это не подходит, строка заранее неизвестна.

Какая строка неизвестна?

Посмотрите ответ сейчас, он отвечает на вопрос?
